# PhoneGap: save a text file in the internal storage accessible when connected to pc

Tags: file, cordova, save, storage

this may seem a repeated question but none of the answers or tutorials I found could help me :( . I'm beginner with the phongap. I would like to save a text file in a specific folder in the internal storage of the android device (android 4.4).

I have used the exact code mentioned in the phonegap documents (the "Full Example" one) and I have given the needed permissions in the manifest.
(http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter)
after compiling it by the phonegap and running it on the device, When I connect the android device to the PC, I can not find the file anywhere. I guess the file is not accessible by the PC.

***The question is*** how should I change the code to make it accessible by PC (when it is connected through USB cable)? so I can copy and paste the text file to the PC.

or is there any sample phonegap project out there that cover this ? so I can try to analyze each line of the codes.

Many thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: Are you sure that it's written and saved perfectly on the device? Check with any file manager(e.g. Astro) in the device that if that file really exists there or not. If the file is written correctly it should have been found by the PC

Comment: Are you really using phonegap 2.6 with android 4.4 like the link to the docs you provided seems to indicate?

Comment: @AtanuCSE no i'm not sure that the file is saved on the device. I have made an index.html according to the link code made the apk with intel XDK (uses Cordova to compile the app) and phonegap as well. After installing and running the app, I expected to find readme.txt in the local storage but I can not find it anywhere.

Comment: You don't answer to the quistion of which version of cordova or phonegap you use. If you use version >= 3, did you actually add the file plugin? And usually on android phones, you have an emulated sdcard in the internal memory of the phone.

Comment: @QuickFix I have used intel XDK as well as phonegap to compile the index.html (codes are exactly same as the link minimum android build is 4.2 but the target build is 4.4) the app shows the html code but there is no readme.txt anywhere, I have checked every single folder of the internal storage (SD card is not installed on the device) that is why I'm confused and I need to see a working app and it codes to see what is wrong. –

Comment: WHAT VERSION OF PHONEGAP ARE YOU USING? The link you provided is about phonegap 2.6 wich is very different from actual versions (version 3.x and version 4). One difference if that with version >=3.0 yoy have to add the file plugin to be able to deal with files.

Comment: @QuickFix Cordova CLI version 3.5 and yes I have added File and File transfer plug in and permission as well. but i did not emulate sdcard in the internal memory! how can i do that? (I have checked the app with sdcard as well but no luck)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read the section [Where to store files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files) in the cordova file plugin documentation.

It will show you the different folders you can use depending on the platform and if the file is public or not.

Here is a code sample on how to write a file `yourfile.txt` to the folder `/Android/data/yourapppackageid/files`. You have to replace `yourapppackageid` with the id of your app which should be accessible from your computer.

```js
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory,
    function(dirEntry) {
        dir.getFile("yourfile.txt", {
            create: true,
            exclusive: false
        }, function(f) {
        f.createWriter(function(writer) {
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                alert("File successfully created!");
            };
            writer.write("Hello world!");
        },
        function(evt, where) {
            console.log("Error writing file "+ where + " :");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(evt));
        }
    },
    function(evt, where) {
        console.log("Error resolving data folder "+ where + " :");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(evt));
    }
);
```