# moving files using cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, file-transfer

So here is what i am trying to acheive.

My app which is develop in cordova.

I am having a file input which will when choosen a file will store the file to the sd card or local memory of the phone.

then i will store the location to the sqlite database.

The problem is i am not able to get the file from source neither i am able to store in sd card.

tried using the following plugins

`org.apache.cordova.file` and `org.apache.cordova.file-transfer`

If you guyz send me any link that will be also a great help.

I have not posted any code because i am completely blank where to start...

Comment: have a look at my answer in this page, maybe it will give you some ideas : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676115/phonegap-save-a-text-file-in-the-internal-storage-accessible-when-connected-to/28748036#28748036

Comment: thanks @QuickFix Actually I am looking for file transfer not creating new file or editing the file.

Comment: anyway the link to the 'Where to store files" section of the file plugin doc should be usefull